# Kubernetes- Persistant volumes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to deploy `Postgresql` through helm on `microk8s`, but pod keeps pending showing `pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims` error.

I tried creating `pvc` and a `storageclass` inside it, and editing it but all keeps pending.

Does anyone know whats holding the `pvc` claiming `pv`?

[image]

Comment: Do you have enough PV matching the requirements in PVC?

Comment: Yup, on the 'PVC' it shows 'no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set' Error

Answer (score 1):

> on the 'PVC' it shows 'no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set' Error

This means that you have to prepare PersistentVolumes for your platform that can be used by your PersistentVolumeClaims (e.g. with correct StorageClass or other requirements)

Comment: I tried making 'PVC' and 'Storage class' but no luck, the PVC keeps pending, do you have any idea on how to troubleshot the connection between them?

Comment: A first step is to show your PVC and StorageClass definition in your question.

Comment: Hey, sorry this is the first time i do a question, the problem occured because i was deploying locally on microk8s, it's solution was to create a 'StorageClass' but not using it, using just a random 'StorageClass' name inside the 'PV' and 'PVC' solved it, thank you Jonas :) .